# Dynamically add or delete rows in a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, model-view-controller

Dynamically add or delete rows in a table using jQuery but how to keep data in arrays after removing a row and don't get the totalSum when I add new row after deleting previous one .row add sucessfully and get initial sum but aftre remove operation i get NAN total sum

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function validation() {
            if (document.getElementById(txt_item).value == "")
                alert("Please Enter a Item name");
            return false;
            if (document.getElementById(txt_price).value == "")
                alert("Please Enter Price");
            return false;
            if (document.getElementById(txt_quantity).value == "")
                alert("Please Enter Quantity");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var itemCount = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var array = [];
            $("#txt_item").focus();
            $("#txt_quantity").keydown(function (e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which
                if (code === 9) {
                    var table = "";
                    var arr = {
                        "Row_ID": itemCount,
                        "TXT_ITEM": $("#txt_item").val(),
                        "TXT_PRICE": $("#txt_price").val(),
                        "TXT_QUANTITY": $("#txt_quantity").val(),
                        "TOTAL_AMOUNT": $("#txt_price").val() * $("#txt_quantity").val()
                    }
                    array.push(arr);
                    itemCount++;
                    table = "<tr id='" + itemCount + "'><td>" + arr['TXT_ITEM'] + "</td><td id='price_"+itemCount+"'>" + arr['TXT_PRICE'] + "</td><td><input type='text' id='quantity_"+itemCount+"' value='" + arr['TXT_QUANTITY'] + "'></td><td id='" + itemCount + "_total'>" + parseInt(arr['TXT_PRICE']) * parseInt(arr['TXT_QUANTITY']) + "</td><td><input type='button' id='" + itemCount + "' class='btn' value='Remove'></td></tr>";
                    $("#test1").append(table);
                    totalSum();
                    $(".btn").click(function () {
                        var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
                        //var value_quantity = $(this).val();
                        //buttonId = buttonId.replace("tr", "").trim();
                        //var value_price = $("#price_" + buttonId).text();
                        //var value_total_price = parseInt($("#"+buttonId+"_total").text());

                        //var tamount=parseInt($("#total_amount").text());
                        //$("#total_amount").text(tamount - value_total_price);
                        ////alert(tamount);
                        //alert(value_total_price);

                        $("#" + buttonId).remove();
                        array.splice(buttonId - 1, 1);
                        //itemCount--;
                        totalSum();
                        Array_IDs();
                                                itemCount = array.length + 1;
});
                    $("#quantity_" + itemCount).keydown(function (e) {
                        var code = e.keyCode || e.which
                        if (code === 9)
                            var value_quantity = $(this).val();
                        var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                        rowId = rowId.replace("tr", "").trim();
                        var value_price = $("#price_" + rowId).text();
                        if (value_quantity >= 0)
                        {
                            $("#" + rowId+"_total").text(value_price * value_quantity);
                            totalSum();
                        }
                    });

                    $("#txt_item").val("");
                    $("#txt_price").val("");
$("#txt_quantity").val("");
                }
                function totalSum() {
                    var total = 0;
                    var rows = array.length;
                    for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
                        total += parseInt($("#" + i + "_total").text());
                        //total += parseInt(array[i].TXT_PRICE * array[i].TXT_QUANTITY);

                    }

                    $("#total_amount").text(total);
                    //alert(total);

                }
                function Array_IDs()
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        array[i].Row_ID = i + 1;
                        //alert(i);
                    }
                    //$("#test1 tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="test1">
        <tr>
            <td>Item Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Total Amount</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_item" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_price" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_quantity" /></td>
                <td id="total_price" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@*<input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add Row" />*@</td>
                <td align="right">Total Amount:</td>
                <td id="total_amount" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>`enter code here`
    </table>
    <table id="test2" width="50%"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

    function validation() {
        if (document.getElementById(txt_item).value == "")
            alert("Please Enter a Item name");
        return false;
        if (document.getElementById(txt_price).value == "")
            alert("Please Enter Price");
        return false;
        if (document.getElementById(txt_quantity).value == "")
            alert("Please Enter Quantity");
        return false;
    }

        var itemCount = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var array = [];
            $("#txt_item").focus();
            $("#txt_quantity").keydown(function (e) {

                var code = e.keyCode || e.which

                if (code === 9) {
                    var table = "";

                    var iPrice = 0;
                    if ($("#txt_price").val() == "" || isNaN($("#txt_price").val())) {
                        iPrice = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        iPrice = parseInt($("#txt_price").val(), 10);
                    }

                    var iQuatity = 0;
                    if ($("#txt_quantity").val() == "" || isNaN($("#txt_quantity").val())) {
                        iQuatity = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        iQuatity = parseInt($("#txt_quantity").val(), 10);
                    }

                    szTotal = iPrice * iQuatity;

                    var arr = {
                        "Row_ID": itemCount,
                        "TXT_ITEM": $("#txt_item").val(),
                        "TXT_PRICE": iPrice,
                        "TXT_QUANTITY": iQuatity,
                        "TOTAL_AMOUNT": szTotal
                    }
                    array.push(arr);
                    itemCount++;
                    table = "<tr id='" + itemCount + "'><td>" + arr['TXT_ITEM'] + "</td><td id='price_" + itemCount + "'>" + arr['TXT_PRICE'] + "</td><td><input type='text' id='quantity_" + itemCount + "' value='" + arr['TXT_QUANTITY'] + "'></td><td class='td_total' id='" + itemCount + "_total'>" + parseInt(arr['TXT_PRICE']) * parseInt(arr['TXT_QUANTITY']) + "</td><td><input type='button' id='" + itemCount + "' class='btn' value='Remove'></td></tr>";

                    $("#test1 tbody").append(table);

                    totalSum();
                    $(".btn").click(function () {
                        var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
                        //var value_quantity = $(this).val();
                        //buttonId = buttonId.replace("tr", "").trim();
                        //var value_price = $("#price_" + buttonId).text();
                        //var value_total_price = parseInt($("#"+buttonId+"_total").text());

                        //var tamount=parseInt($("#total_amount").text());
                        //$("#total_amount").text(tamount - value_total_price);
                        ////alert(tamount);
                        //alert(value_total_price);

                        $("#" + buttonId).remove();
                        array.splice(buttonId - 1, 1);
                        //itemCount--;
                        totalSum();
                        Array_IDs();
                        itemCount = array.length + 1;
                    });
                    $("#quantity_" + itemCount).keydown(function (e) {
                        var code = e.keyCode || e.which
                        if (code === 9)
                            var value_quantity = 0;
                        if ($(this).val() != "" && !isNaN($(this).val()))
                        {
                            value_quantity = parseInt($(this).val(),10)
                        }
                        var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                        rowId = rowId.replace("tr", "").trim();
                        var value_price = 0;
                        if ($("#price_" + rowId).text() != "" && !isNaN($("#price_" + rowId).text())) {
                            value_price=parseInt($("#price_" + rowId).text(),10);
                        }
                        if (value_quantity >= 0) {
                            $("#" + rowId + "_total").text(value_price * value_quantity);
                            totalSum();
                        }
                    });

                    $("#txt_item").val("");
                    $("#txt_price").val("");
                    $("#txt_quantity").val("");
                }
                function totalSum() {
                    var total = 0;
                    //var rows = array.length;
                    //for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
                    //    total += parseInt($("#" + i + "_total").text());
                    //    //total += parseInt(array[i].TXT_PRICE * array[i].TXT_QUANTITY);

                    //}

                    $('.td_total').each(function () {

                        if (!isNaN($.trim($(this).text())) && $.trim($(this).text()) != "")
                        {
                            total = total+parseInt($(this).text(),10)
                        }

                    });
                    $("#total_amount").text(total);
                    //alert(total);

                }
                function Array_IDs() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        array[i].Row_ID = i + 1;
                        //alert(i);
                    }
                    //$("#test1 tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="test1">
        <tr>
            <td>Item Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Total Amount</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_item" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_price" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_quantity" /></td>
                <td id="total_price" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@*<input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add Row" />*@</td>
                <td align="right">Total Amount:</td>
                <td id="total_amount" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>`enter code here`
    </table>
    <table id="test2" width="50%"></table>
</body>
</html>
```